# iOS App How to Submit Google OAuth Verification to Use Google Calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

Hi While using Google Calendar in my iOS APP, the screen prompts a warning like as bellow

***This app isn't verified by google yet...

only proceed if you know and trust the developer***

To avoid this warning I need to submit **my iOS App to `Google OAuth Verification`**

I searched in different sites but i didn't get a clear doc to **Submit An iOS App for Google OAuth Verification.**

Could someone help to provide the steps/guidelines link to **Submit An iOS App for Google OAuth Verification.**

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the google developer console Under credentials

[image]

You will find the consent screen tab

[image]

At the very bottom of this page you will find a button

[image]

Before submiting you should read though the information provided on that page along with the links

> OAuth verification
>
> To protect you and your users, your consent screen
> and application may need to be verified by Google. Verification is
> required if your app is marked as Public and at least one of the
> following is true:
>
> - Your app uses a sensitive and/or restricted scope
> - Your app displays an icon on its OAuth consent screen
> - Your app has a large number of
>   authorized domains
> - You have made changes to a previously-verified
>   OAuth consent screen The verification process may take up to several
>   weeks, and you will receive email updates as it progresses. Learn more
>   about [verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).
>
> Before your consent screen and application are verified by Google, you
> can still test your application with limitations. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) about how
> your app will behave before it's verified.

Comment: Thank you Dalm To for the detailed explanation I will check as you suggested... thanks once again